# CodeMirror on change failing

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am creating two code mirror instances from text areas in my form, and I need those hidden text areas to be updated before submission. I have added on on change event to the script but it doesn't seem to work.

can anyone help?
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function editor(id) {
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(id, {
                continuousScanning: 500,
                lineNumbers: true
            });
            editor.setSize(900, 600);
        }
    var config_id = document.getElementById('id_config')
    var config = editor(config_id);
    var remote_config_id = document.getElementById('id_remote_config')
    var remote_config = editor(remote_config_id);

    config.on('change',function(cMirror){
        // get value right from instance
        config_id.value = cMirror.getValue();
    });
    remote_config.on('change',function(cMirror){
        // get value right from instance
        remote_config_id.value = cMirror.getValue();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `change` event for that: CodeMirror listens to changes of the hidden text area, so changing the value would fire another `change` event. That could cause endless loops.

The documentation contains the correct approach:

> the library provides a much more powerful shortcut:
>
> `var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);`
>
> This will, among other things, **ensure that the textarea's value is updated with the editor's contents when the form (if it is part of a form) is submitted**.

That means you have a bug in the code which you didn't show above. Maybe you're using a weird way to submit the form, so CodeMirror can't notice and update the value?

One option would be to remove CodeMirror in the JavaScript which submits the form.

Comment: hmm, looking into this I think it might be my server side code that is not working. when I submit the form, the update remains and the page reloads, however when I refresh the page the old content comes back